# Encapsulating AJAX using ES6 Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to encapsulate AJAX loader.

The code is like this:

```
const $ = require('jquery');

class ModelLoader {
    static loadCsvFile(path, callback, options) {
        this.callback = callback;
        $.get(path, this._loadCsvFile);
    }

    static _loadCsvFile(data) {
        ModelLoader.callback(); // using this.callback() doesn't work because this here is AJAX object
    }
}

module.exports = ModelLoader;
```

The problem is that when users write code like this:

```
ModelLoader.loadCsvFile('model1.csv', callback1);
ModelLoader.loadCsvFile('model2.csv', callback2);
```

Both of them will go into `callback2` because `this.callback` becomes `callback2` before the first `_loadCsvFile(data)` is invoked.

Is there any elegant solution to encapsulate AJAX?

Comment: Is there anything else you do inside of `_loadCsvFile_` besides `ModelLoader.callback`?

Comment: Why not just pass the callback right inside `$.get(path, callback)` and not store it anywhere?

Comment: Don't write `class`es with only static members. If you really need such an object, use an object literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your reasoning behind keeping the callback in the class?
In `_loadCsvFile`, I would just pass the callback and call it there, like this:

```
class ModelLoader {
    loadCsvFile(path, callback, options) {
        $.get(path, (data) => {
            this._loadCsvFile(data, callback);
        });
    }

    _loadCsvFile(data, callback) {
        callback(); // using this.callback() doesn't work because this here is AJAX object
    }
}
```

Please note that I got rid of the `static` keyword in `loadCsvFile` since it cannot be static (since you're calling `this` inside that function).

Comment: I've tested it. It works well if both of the methods are `static`.

Comment: Your comment is inaccurate, `this.callback` would work perfectly if it was stored on the instance

Comment: But that means that the class would not be static, i.e., for each callback you would have to create a new instance of the `ModelLoader` object.